# The host value of mysql account is '%', but access denied when login

Tags: mysql, docker

I used Docker to create a nacos container (172.17.0.5) and a mysql container (172.17.0.4). 
And I added a mysql account **with host '%'**, but could not log in to mysql from this account in the nacos container, error information is: 
`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'nacos'@'172.17.0.5' (using password: YES)`

> [root@aa64d3cb2722 nacos]# mysql -h172.17.0.4 -P3306 -unacos -p
> Enter password:
> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'nacos'@'172.17.0.5' (using password: YES)
> [root@aa64d3cb2722 nacos]#

However, I managed to log in after changing '%' to the IP of the nacos container (172.17.0.5).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXmA8.jpg)

Why is that? Wouldn't setting host to '%' enable logins for all ip?

Comment: Always is a good practice to check the logs.

Comment: Check if the account `'nacos'@'172.17.0.5'` (not `'nacos'@'%'`) exists.

Comment: @ErgestBasha I checked the error.log of mysql, but there is only one sentence in the log message that I mentioned before.

Comment: @Akina I can log in successfully when I log in with an account whose host is "172.17.0.5", but isn't "%" a universal match?

Comment: `'nacos'@'172.17.0.5'` and `'nacos'@'%'` are two different accounts which may have different permissions. When you authenticate from `172.17.0.5` then first account should be used, when you authenticate from another host then `'nacos'@'%'` will be used. Read reference manual, the difference between USER() and CURRENT_USER() functions output.

Comment: @Akina Thank you, I re-checked the account's permission and found that "nacos@%" had an "Alter" permission that I accidentally cancelled. Now I have re-granted the account with complete permission and can log in successfully.